# DB2 sql group by/count distinct column values

Tags: sql, db2

if I have a table with values like this:

```
ID  SUBID    FLAG
-----------------
 1      1       1
 1      2  (null)
 2      3       1
 2      3  (null)
 3      4       1
 4      5       1
 4      6  (null)
 5      7       0
 6      8  (null)
 7      9       1
```

and I would like to get all the ID's where 'FLAG' is only set to 1, so in this case the query would return

```
ID  SUBID    FLAG
-----------------
 3      4       1
 7      9       1
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM flags where flag=1
and ID NOT in( SELECT ID FROM flags where flag !=1 OR flag IS NULL)
```

Comment: np, you actually can remove the flag !=1 if the only option on the flag column is 1 and nulls but keep it if you can have a "2" for example

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a db2 instance to test on but this might work:

```
select t1.id, t1.subid, t1.flag
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select id 
  from yourtable 
  group by id
  having count(id) = 1
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.flag = 1;
```

Comment: `FLAG` can also be `0`, judging by the OP's example. Your query wouldn't work correctly if there was a row with flag 1 and another one with the same ID and flag 0.

Comment: @AndriyM you are correct, fixed - working on sql server fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f6e4/7